# Uipinchgesturerecognizer zoom image with specific location (Not from Center) - IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, pinchzoom, zooming, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I want to zoom image using pinch gesture zoom image with **specific location/coordinate** (Not from center).

I don't want to use scrollview, because of when i zoom image with specific location at that time user can drag image also, so i want to stop dragging (panning) at zooming time, in short i want to stop dragging.

Please suggest code in swift 3 if possible.

Comment: Hi Atul, Did you solved your problem? I'm also looking for the same type of interaction.